# How to speed up tables transfer between Access and SQL Server using VBA?

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, t-sql, ms-access

I am trying to move tables from access to SQL Server programmatically.
I have some limitation in the system permissions, ie: I cannot use OPENDATASOURCE or OPENROWSET.

What I want to achieve is to transfer some table from Access to SQL Server and then work on that tables through vba (excel)/python and T-SQL.

The problem is in the timing that it is required to move the tables.
My current process is:

1. I work with vba macros, importing data from excel and making same transformation in access, to then import into the SQL Server
2. destroy the table in the server: "DROP TABLE"
3. re-importing the table with DoCmd.TransferDatabase

What I have notice is that the operation seems to be done based on a batch of rows and not directly. It is taking 1 minutes and half each 1000 rows. The same operation on Access it would have taken few seconds.

I understood that it is a specific way of SQL Server to use import by batches of 10 rows, probably to have more access on data: [Micorsoft details](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb188204(v=sql.90).aspx)

But in the above process I just want a copy the table from access to the SQL as fast as possible as then I would avoid cross platform links and I will perform operation only on the SQL Server.

Which would be the faster way to achieve this goal?

Comment: The 10-rows-at-a-time is for fetching data from Sql Server into Access, not for inserting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to increase performance for bulk INSERTs to ODBC linked tables in Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25863473/how-to-increase-performance-for-bulk-inserts-to-odbc-linked-tables-in-access)

Comment: (While the question is about Oracle, the answer is for SQL Server.) -- See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32759978/how-to-increase-performance-for-bulk-inserts-to-odbc-linked-tables-in-access-for

Comment: Why use Access tables at all? Whatever you do with the access table can be done with a second SQL table linked to access, assuming it is not possible to do what you need with just a single table.

Comment: Hi, because I cannot import excel files into SQL Sever as functions like OPENDATASOURCE or OPENROWSET are blocked.then for same simple operation Access is strangely faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are functions like OPENDATASOURCE or OPENROWSET are blocked?  Do you work in a bank?

I can't say for sure which solution is the absoute fastest, but you may want to consider exporting all Access tables as separate CSV files (or Excel files), and then run a small script to load each of those files into SQL Server.

Here is some VBA code that saves separate tables as separate files.

```
Dim obj As AccessObject, dbs As Object
Set dbs = Application.CurrentData
For Each obj In dbs.AllTables
If Left(obj.Name, 4) <> "MSys" Then
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , obj.Name, obj.Name & ".csv", True
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, obj.Name, obj.Name & ".xls", True
End If
Next obj
```

Now, you can very easily, and very quickly, load CSV files into SQL Server using Bulk Insert.

```
Create TestTable

USE TestData
GO
CREATE TABLE CSVTest
(ID INT,
FirstName VARCHAR(40),
LastName VARCHAR(40),
BirthDate SMALLDATETIME)
GO

BULK
INSERT CSVTest
FROM 'c:\csvtest.txt'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
--Check the content of the table.
SELECT *
FROM CSVTest
GO
--Drop the table to clean up database.
DROP TABLE CSVTest
GO
```

https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/06/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-bulk-insert-load-comma-delimited-file-into-sql-server/

Also, you may want to consider one of these options.

https://www.online-tech-tips.com/ms-office-tips/ms-access-to-sql-database/

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/move-access-data-to-a-sql-server-database-by-using-the-upsizing-wizard-5d74c0df-c8cd-4867-8d07-e6e759d72924