# Speed up inserts into SQL Server from pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

In `python`, I have a process to select data from one database (`Redshift` via `psycopg2`), then insert that data into `SQL Server` (via `pyodbc`).  I chose to do a read / write rather than a read / flat file / load  because the row count is around 100,000 per day.  Seemed easier to simply connect and insert.  However - the insert process is slow, taking several minutes.

Is there a better way to insert data into SQL Server with Pyodbc?

```
select_cursor.execute(output_query)

done = False
rowcount = 0

while not done:
    rows = select_cursor.fetchmany(10000)

    insert_list = []

    if rows == []:
        done = True
        break

    for row in rows:
        rowcount += 1

        insert_params = (
            row[0], 
            row[1], 
            row[2]
            )

        insert_list.append(insert_params)            

    insert_cnxn = pyodbc.connect('''Connection Information''')

    insert_cursor = insert_cnxn.cursor()

    insert_cursor.executemany("""
        INSERT INTO Destination (AccountNumber, OrderDate, Value)
        VALUES (?, ?, ?)
        """, insert_list)

    insert_cursor.commit()
    insert_cursor.close()
    insert_cnxn.close()

select_cursor.close()
select_cnxn.close()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPDATE:** pyodbc 4.0.19 added a `Cursor#fast_executemany` option that can greatly improve performance by avoiding the behaviour described below. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47057189/2144390) for details.

---

Your code does follow proper form (aside from the few minor tweaks mentioned in the other answer), but be aware that when pyodbc performs an `.executemany` what it actually does is submit a separate `sp_prepexec` for each individual row. That is, for the code

```python
sql = "INSERT INTO #Temp (id, txtcol) VALUES (?, ?)"
params = [(1, 'foo'), (2, 'bar'), (3, 'baz')]
crsr.executemany(sql, params)
```

the SQL Server actually performs the following (as confirmed by SQL Profiler)

```sql
exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,N'@P1 bigint,@P2 nvarchar(3)',N'INSERT INTO #Temp (id, txtcol) VALUES (@P1, @P2)',1,N'foo'
exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,N'@P1 bigint,@P2 nvarchar(3)',N'INSERT INTO #Temp (id, txtcol) VALUES (@P1, @P2)',2,N'bar'
exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,N'@P1 bigint,@P2 nvarchar(3)',N'INSERT INTO #Temp (id, txtcol) VALUES (@P1, @P2)',3,N'baz'
```

So, for an `.executemany` "batch" of 10,000 rows you would be

- performing 10,000 individual inserts,
- with 10,000 round-trips to the server, and
- sending the identical SQL command text (`INSERT INTO ...`) 10,000 times.

It is *possible* to have pyodbc send an initial `sp_prepare` and then do an `.executemany` calling `sp_execute`, but the nature of `.executemany` is that you still would do 10,000 `sp_prepexec` calls, just executing `sp_execute` instead of `INSERT INTO ...`. That could improve performance if the SQL statement was quite long and complex, but for a short one like the example in your question it probably wouldn't make all that much difference.

One could also get creative and build "table value constructors" as illustrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25879264/2144390), but notice that it is only offered as a "Plan B" when native bulk insert mechanisms are not a feasible solution.

Comment: Wow.  I didn't know that `executemany` did that. Is there any (performance-related) reason to prefer it as opposed to individual calls to `execute` then?

Comment: No, I haven't seen any evidence that `.executemany` does anything different from an explicit loop with individual `.execute` calls, at least using SQL Server ODBC drivers on Windows. pymssql sends individually constructed `INSERT` statements for each row when performing an `.executemany`, so it looks like `.executemany` is really just a coding shortcut, at least for SQL Server. (OTOH, MySQL Connector/Python actually does rewrite `INSERT`s for `.executemany`, according to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html).)

Answer (score 0):

<s>It's good that you're already using `executemany()`.</s>  [*Struck out after reading other answer.*]

It should speed up a (very little) bit if you move the `connect()` and `cursor()` calls for your `insert_cnxn` and `insert_cursor` outside of your while loop.  (Of course, if you do this, you should also move the 2 corresponding `close()` calls outside of the loop as well.)  In addition to not having to (re)establish the connection every time, re-using the cursor will prevent having to recompile the SQL each time.

However, you probably won't see a huge speed up from this just because you're probably only making ~10 passes through that loop anyway (given that you said ~100,000 a day and your loop groups together 10,000 at a time).

One other thing you might look into is whether there are any "behind-the-scenes" conversions being made on your `OrderDate` parameter.  You can go to SQL Server Management Studio and look at the execution plan of the query. (Look for your insert query in the "recent expensive queries" list by right-clicking on the server node and choosing "Activity Monitor"; right click on the insert query and look at its Execution Plan.)