# SqlAlchemy+pymssql. Will raw parametrized queries use same execution plan?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pymssql

In my application I have parametrized queries like this:

```
res = db_connection.execute(text("""
        SELECT * FROM Luna_gestiune WHERE id_filiala = :id_filiala AND  anul=:anul AND luna = :luna
        """), 
     id_filiala=6, anul=2010, luna=7).fetchone()
```

Will such query use same query execution plan if I run it in loop with different parameter values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems unlikely. pymssql uses FreeTDS, and FreeTDS performs the parameter substitution *before* sending the query to the server, unlike some other mechanisms that send the query "template" and the parameters separately (e.g., pyodbc with Microsoft's ODBC drivers, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40065211/2144390)).

That is, for the query you describe in your question, pymssql/FreeTDS will not send a query string like

```sql
SELECT * FROM Luna_gestiune WHERE id_filiala = @P1 AND anul = @P2 AND luna = @P3
```

along with separate values for @P1 = 6, @P2 = 2010, etc.. Instead it will build the literal query first, and then send

```sql
SELECT * FROM Luna_gestiune WHERE id_filiala = 6 AND anul = 2010 AND luna = 7
```

So for each parameteized query you send, the SQL command text will be different, and my understanding is that database engines will only re-use a cached execution plan if the current command text is *identical* to the cached version.

**Edit:** Subsequent testing confirms that pymssql apparently *does not* re-use cached execution plans. Details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40156617/2144390).