# Is parameter binding implemented correctly in pymssql library?

Tags: python, sql-server, query-optimization, sql-execution-plan, pymssql

I'm calling extremely simple query from Python program using pymsqsql library.

```
 with self.conn.cursor() as cursor:
     cursor.execute('select extra_id from mytable where id = %d', id)
     extra_id = cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

Note that parameter binding is used as described in [pymssql documentation](http://pymssql.org/en/stable/pymssql_examples.html).

One of the main goals of parameter binding is providing ability for DBMS engine to cache the query plan. I connected to MS SQL with Profiler and checked what queries are actually executed. It turned out that each time a unique statement gets executed (with its own bound ID). I also checked query usage with such query:

```
select * from sys.dm_exec_cached_plans ec
cross apply
sys.dm_exec_sql_text(ec.plan_handle) txt
where  txt.text like '%select extra_id from mytable where id%'
```

And it shown that the plan is not reused (which is expectable of course due to unique text of each query). This differs much from parameter binding when querying from C#, when we can see that queries are the same but the supplied parameters are different.

So I wonder if I am using pymssql correctly and whether this lib is appropriate for using with MS SQL DBMS.

*P.S. I know that MS SQL has a feature of auto-parameterization which works for basic queries, but it is not guarantied, and may not work for complex queries.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using pymssql correctly. It is true that pymssql actually does substitute the parameter values into the SQL text before sending the query to the server. For example:

pymssql:

```sql
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE id=1
```

pyodbc with Microsoft's ODBC Driver for SQL Server (not the FreeTDS ODBC driver):

```sql
exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,N'@P1 int',N'SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE id=@P1',1
```

However, bear in mind that pymssql is based on FreeTDS and the above behaviour appears to be a function of the way FreeTDS handles parameterized queries, rather than a specific feature of pymssql *per se*.

And yes, it can have implications for the re-use of execution plans (and hence performance) as illustrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40156617/2144390).

Comment: Thanks. Regardless of culprit part, this is a reason to not to use pymssql in some cases...

Comment: This actually doesn't seem to be a FreeTDS thing.  I used FreeTDS with PYODBC and I got beautiful paramerterized sql.  Trace confirmed it to be true.  Just in case anyone runs across this in the future.  One downside to FreeTDS+Pyodbc is it runs into the multi bug on chunksize even when you don't specify it with SQL Server, unlike microsofts driver.

Comment: Here is the code responsible for this evil https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql/blob/master/src/pymssql/_mssql.pyx#L2058-L2113